# Possible to make the bones visible when the mouse is hovering over a rigged model?

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones

I was thinking something like in sfm (source filmmaker), cause the bones are often in my way, but when you hover over the model that has bones and is rigged, the bones automatically becomes xray, but when you take your mouse away, the bones are no longer visible. I was just watching this video, and i saw that the bones were only visible when his mouse was over it, take a look: https://youtu.be/FtBdRE5lRRU?t=178

Scouts (the model he is posing) bones are only visible when he actually has his hands over the model, i would love if there was something like this possible in blender.

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to may that in blender unless you do some coding, one thing you can do is make custom bone shapes and check the wireframe box on the bone settings

Comment: I agree this would have to be with some custom coding. The closest Blender has to controlling how many bones you see is the *Armature Layer* panel.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's currently no way to do it without coding a custom solution that will hide bones and only show them on mouse hover. This would actually be very cool if we had something like this as default on blender (with maybe a slider to customize mouse distance-to-bone activation, etc) but as of today we dont.

The best similar solution that I can think of is an addon that is called Skin Selection, unfortunately, it's paid.

https://www.blendernation.com/2017/09/18/add-skin-selection/

This is a video of it working:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8AOj-nDn2o

It allows you to select a bone by selecting the surface of the mesh as if it was the bone... and allows for multiple controllers to be assigned to similar regions of the mesh. So nothing gets in the way, every bone is hidden.

I have not bought it to experiment and say how hard it is to configure, or how automated it is, but I'd advise you to check it out, its not that expensive.